# floating label effect remove when the required is remove too

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

is there a way I can use for the floating Label on bootstrap 4, when im removing the required on the input the label stay's at the top of the border.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.form-group input').on('focus', function() {
    $(this).siblings('label').addClass('active');
  });

  $('.form-group input').on('blur', function() {
    if (!$(this).val() && !$(this).attr('required')) {
      $(this).siblings('label').removeClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.appointment {
  padding-top: 49px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.form-group {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

a:hover {
  color: blue;
  transition: .5s;
}

.form-group input {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

.form-group label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: gray;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0.2s ease-out all;
  z-index: 2;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.form-group input:focus,
.form-group input:valid {
  border-color: #ced4da;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.25);
}

.form-group input:focus+label,
.form-group input:valid+label {
  top: 0;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  color: #555;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" class="form-control" required>
        <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <input type="text" id="middlename" name="middlename" class="form-control">
        <label for="middlename">Middle Name</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" class="form-control" required>
        <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center">
    <label>
      <a href="{{ route('index') }}"><i class="icofont-bubble-left"></i> Back to Home</a>
    </label>
  </div>
  <br>
</form>
```

as you can see i on my script, i don't know what is incorrect or something i missing, why the label is floating already even if it is reload or not focus.

Comment: `.form-group input:valid+label` - that selector can't match, if the input does not have the required attribute set - because then it does not _have_ a valid (or invalid) state.

Comment: i remove and it still works, what my problem is whenever i remove the required on the input (middle name) the label is already on the top, on the css and script am i missing something?

Comment: @CBroe is there a way i can select the input without the required?

Comment: This selects the label, not the input. But based on whether the input is in valid state, or not. (So that the label gets shown above, when the field is not empty.) But without required, there _is_ no valid or invalid state - which means, you can not "detect" this case using CSS alone, you will have to involve JavaScript. (Which by the looks of it you already attempted, but without any `active` class in your CSS, toggling that class on and off can't have much of an effect.)

Comment: @CBroe here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ev8bk9hu/1 the `input:valid` is applying to the input that does not have `required` - so it is always valid.

Comment: @freedomn-m right, if it is not required, then it is of course always valid, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest workaround (IMHO) - modify the selector, to use a class `.valid` instead of the `:valid` pseudo class, and then toggle that class on the input field itself, based on whether it is empty or not.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.form-group input').on('blur', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('valid', $(this).val() !== '');
  });
});
```

```css
.appointment {
  padding-top: 49px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.form-group {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.form-group .col {
  position: relative;
}

a:hover {
  color: blue;
  transition: .5s;
}

.form-group input {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

.form-group label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: gray;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0.2s ease-out all;
  z-index: 2;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.form-group input:focus,
.form-group input:valid {
  border-color: #ced4da;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.25);
}

.form-group input:focus+label,
.form-group input.valid+label {
  top: 0;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  color: #555;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" class="form-control" required>
        <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <input type="text" id="middlename" name="middlename" class="form-control">
        <label for="middlename">Middle Name</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" class="form-control" required>
        <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center">
    <label>
      <a href="{{ route('index') }}"><i class="icofont-bubble-left"></i> Back to Home</a>
    </label>
  </div>
  <br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The culprit is this CSS line:

```
.form-group input:valid+label
```

The label is formatted when the field is not required, hence valid.

In your demo you are also missing Bootstrap's CSS, add the line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.form-group input').on('focus', function() {
    $(this).siblings('label').addClass('active');
  });

  $('.form-group input').on('blur', function() {
    if (!$(this).val() && !$(this).attr('required')) {
      $(this).siblings('label').removeClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.appointment {
  padding-top: 49px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.form-group {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

a:hover {
  color: blue;
  transition: .5s;
}

.form-group input {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

.form-group label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: gray;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0.2s ease-out all;
  z-index: 2;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.form-group input:focus,
.form-group input:valid {
  border-color: #ced4da;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.25);
}

.form-group input:focus+label
 {
  top: 0;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  color: #555;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" class="form-control" required>
        <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <input type="text" id="middlename" name="middlename" class="form-control">
        <label for="middlename">Middle Name</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" class="form-control" required>
        <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center">
    <label>
      <a href="{{ route('index') }}"><i class="icofont-bubble-left"></i> Back to Home</a>
    </label>
  </div>
  <br>
</form>
```

Comment: the bootstrap is on the @extends('layouts.homepage') im using laravel, on the answer you provided the middle name is already on the top. what i want is even the required is gone/remove the label would be inside the textbos then if click it will float